# How to customize domain name of firebase database, auth and storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I know that I can customize domain name for firebase hosting.
But how can I customize the firebase database, auth and storage domain name?
eg.

```
authDomain: example.firebaseapp.com => auth.example.com
databaseURL: example.firebaseio.com => db.example.com
storageBucket: example.appspot.com => storage.example.com
```

I tried to cname the domain (eg cname auth.example.com to example.firebaseapp.com)
but this cause the https://auth.example.com shows the certificate error.
can I resolve that?

Comment: You can't just CNAME because that would break the SSL host name verification for those names.  https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation  Why do you need to change these, anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase doesn't offer the ability to whitelabel our services under your own domain.

You could choose to proxy all traffic through Hosting + Cloud Functions, but that would be a significant amount of additional work.

What is the need to offer your own custom domain on these services?

Comment: I was looking for this option as well, in my case I wanted to be able to create a cname so that I could cache specific .json endpoints. I can't control the caching for example.firebaseio.com/clients.json but I can with data.example.com/clients.json

Is there another possible solution to this?

Comment: Because firebaseio.com was blocked in China, so we need use  custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also change the firebase script snippet in your code?

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "yourkey",
    authDomain: "auth.example.com",
    databaseURL: "https://db.example.com",
    projectId: "yourid",
    storageBucket: "storage.example.com",
    messagingSenderId: "id"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using angular and I've changed the configure to that domian. The problem is, the certificate of firebase db or others just only effective in *.firebaseio.com ,so when I cname db.example.com to it, the browser will show the certificate  error.(https)

Comment: Any mentions of the old domain name in your code? If not I'm not sure what the problem could be..